What's name of movie where teenagers die in real life if they died in virtual reality?
Humans (teenagers) get all the damage that they got in VR, not only die. It's not the movie "Stay Alive". I remember that it was not a simple video game but virtual reality. Also, I remember that in the last scene, the killer got hit and because of it got a big hole in his body in real life.
The place was like an underground parking but I'm not sure. The villain is one of the characters shown previously in the movie. Sorry for the description, I was a kid. I guess it's from 2008 or earlier, from US or Europe, in English or German but not sure. Sorry for my English.

Please provide as many details as possible: Year, language, characters, scenes etc., literally anything you might remember. This will really help out.

Thanks for the details, they certainly helped. Added & posted a possible match.

Sounds like horror film Subterano from 2003.

In a future society apparently ruled by virtual games, Conrad (Alex Dimitriades), the leader of a revolutionary group called "The Orphans", escapes from the guards when he was going to be executed, and with the support of his girlfriend Gracie (Tasma Walton), he goes to the last level of a parking garage trying to escape to a sanctuary. However, the garage is shut down by a crazy teenager that has developed a new version of a deadly game called Subterano, and Conrad and Gracie, with four teenagers, a security guard and an elder accountant have to play the game and fight to survive.

In the end, the villain is hit in the game and as a result has a big hole in his torso in real life. The trailer:



